# CS50 IDE can't upload file in input with name attribute. If i do so I get error 500

Tags: file, ide, cs50

The code is very simple

this is flask

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

and this is html

```
<form  action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="hello">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I upload file I get error 500. But if there is no name then it works fine.
If i do the same thing on other IDE there is no problem with that. Does anyone have any ideas???

Comment: If you get error 500, there is definitely more info in the flask log (in the terminal where `flask run` is executed).

Comment: That's the problem. The terminal doesn't say anything even about the error.

Comment: The error is not reproducible with this code. Check that the html is valid; check the browser console for errors.